# Cyclic packetloss out drop

Tags: networking, server, minecraft

Im using ubuntu 18.04 and i dont know where else can i find some help about this issue.

Im hosting Minecraft and teamspeak server and once in a while im getting huge packetloss out. That is happening to both servers so i dont think that it's some bug with that platforms. I was thinking about ddos, but would it affect in packets, not out? And im using OVH Game server and it dont send ddos attack report and enabling constant mitigation didnt help as well.

I dont have any ideas how else can i check whats going on and how can i fix that

Comment: `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` (in a terminal window) will show timestamped log messages.

Comment: I dont have this NetworkManager there :/

Comment: Okay i installed it and would wait for the next issue